# Generating a migration with custom SQL code in Phoenix

Tags: sql, elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I want to generate a new `Ecto` Migration with custom SQL code instead of using the provided helpers. The current `mix` generator tasks handle only models.

How can I write raw SQL code in a migration?

Answer (score 7):

First create a new migration using the provided Mix Task and call it whatever you want:

```
$ mix ecto.gen.migration my_custom_migration
```

Now edit the newly generated migration module in your `priv/repo/migrations/` and replace the empty `change` method with `up` and `down` methods.

You can then call [`execute/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Migration.html#execute/1) with your raw `SQL` code in them:

```
defmodule MyApp.Repo.Migrations.MyCustomMigration do
  use Ecto.Migration

  def up do
    # Your custom SQL code
    execute "CREATE TABLE some_table ..."
  end

  def down do
    execute "DROP TABLE some_table;"
  end
end
```

---

Source: [Execute Raw SQL In An Ecto Migration](https://til.hashrocket.com/posts/f5a0cafa7e-execute-raw-sql-in-an-ecto-migration)